# How do I create a powerup that affects speed for a limited amount of time?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2, effect-modifier

I am looking to create a powerup such that when the "playership" object collides with it will affect the playership's speed for a few seconds, let's say 30-60 seconds. I cannot seem to figure this out on my own nor do I know what to look up, so I am asking on here for some help.

I have this for my playership:

```
y += sign(mouse_y - y) * global.Speedy;
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation can be done on the `playership` object. You need to track the power-up additional speed (let's call it `powerup_speed`) and the overall bonus duration time (`powerup_countdown`). On `playership`:

*Create Event:*

```
powerup_speed = 0;
powerup_countdown = 0;
```

The power-up effects occur only when the timer is a positive value. This is a countdown timer: As long as it is greater than `0`, we set the bonus speed to an arbitrary value and reduce the timer by `1`. Otherwise, the bonus is inactive and we reset the bonus speed:

*Step Event:*

```
if (powerup_countdown > 0)
{
    powerup_speed = 10;  // Change as needed
    powerup_countdown = powerup_countdown - 1;
}
else
{
    powerup_speed = 0;  // Reset bonus speed
}
```

Please note, the timer is defined as game steps, not seconds: *n* seconds = *n* * `room_speed` steps.

Then, you change the code snippet controlling the `y` position as follows:

```
y += sign(mouse_y - y) * (global.Speedy + powerup_speed);
```

This way, your power-up logic should be up and working. Applying the power-up to the `playership` object is just a value assignment when the collision occurs:

*Collision Event:*

```
playership.powerup_countdown = 30 * room_speed;  // Power-up lasts for 30 secs
```